# Putting a PHP response into a table

Tags: php, foreach, response

I send a link to server and get a response.
in the code I print the response.
I want to now put the response into a table,
I am wondering if someone can help me get started (maybe just the first of 10 lines?

```
print_r($response);
```

The response I get looks like ( I was thinking counting every colon and a "foreach", but sometimes there is a null variable without " ")
Hoping someone can get me started here .

> [{"name":"Tanya Lea","city":"Cambridge","state_province":null,"country_code":"CA","country_name":"Canada","signed_at":"2015-12-12T15:04:27Z"},{"name":"Jeff Bell","city":"Ottawa","state_province":null,"country_code":"CA","country_name":"Canada","signed_at":"2015-12-12T05:15:42Z"},{"name":"Jacqueline Taylor","city":"ottawa","state_province":null,"country_code":"CA","country_name":"Canada","signed_at":"2015-12-11T15:06:45Z"}]

Comment: I have used this plugin that converts json to table. https://github.com/marianoguerra/json.human.js

Comment: Thank you;
I will check this out now!

Comment: A little over my head, and I think I learn more by doing it manually but I have kept this on file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sure there is a better way to do this, with "for each" or something,
but a few hours later I have at least learned something and have used this,
The part that took me forever was $json_array[0]["name"]
I kept putting the [0] after ["name']
 (I will only post first 2 out of 10)

```
    $json_array = json_decode($response, true);
    echo "<table border='1'><tr><td>Name: </td><td>", $json_array[0]["name"];
    echo "</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td>City: </td><td>", $json_array[0]["city"];
    echo "</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td>Province: </td><td>", $json_array[0]["state_province"];
    echo "</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td>Country: </td><td>", $json_array[0]["country_name"];
    echo "</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td>Time: </td><td>", $json_array[0]["signed_at"];
    echo "</td></tr>";
    echo "</table>";
    echo "<table border='1'><tr><td>Name: </td><td>", $json_array[1]["name"];
    echo "</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td>City: </td><td>", $json_array[1]["city"];
    echo "</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td>Province: </td><td>", $json_array[1]["state_province"];
    echo "</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td>Country: </td><td>", $json_array[1]["country_name"];
    echo "</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td>Time: </td><td>", $json_array[1]["signed_at"];
    echo "</td></tr>";
    echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$output = print_r($response, true);
```

Now save `$output` variable in database, database field should be `text` datatype..

Comment: Thanx, I have it working now but will still work on a for/each method